# Nginx-wordpress Server showing welcome page after update

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ubuntu-server

So i just updated my RPI yesterday and since then, instead of my default homepage the server shows the standard nginx welcome page when i type in my domain. It still works when i add something to the plain domain address like: mydomain.net/something; in that case it will show up the homepage. wp-mydamin also works

To be honest, i don't really understand much about webservers in general. I Just frickled on this thing last year until it was working since then i just used the wordpress webinterface.

any ideas?

Update:

"Do you mean that the same site was available at domain.com but after your update it is only accessible at domain.com/subfolder?"

exactly this!

update procedure was as follows:

sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade & sudo reboot

here is the current nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the same site was available at domain.com but after your update it is only accessible at domain.com/subfolder?

Comment: @Marc, please provide more details. At least your `nginx` config, update procedure, anything to start from.